# replace bracket with HTML less-than character

Tags: javascript, angularjs, replace

I use AngularJS and have this code:

```
return text.replace("[", "<");
```

I expect it to add the < as a HTML character but it does not. It adds it as visible text. That way it print out the HTML code on the page.

How do I replace the less-than character `<`, without converting it to a text character?

**Content of text**

Before replace...

```
[div class="rating-container"]
```

**HTML code**

I added this, it's a value and a filter.

```
{{post.rating.html | replace_brackets }}
```

***I tried to wrap it with***

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="post.rating.html | replace_brackets"></div>
```

but it just gave white nothing. No errors but no output.

Comment: show me the content of `text`

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan Added "Content of text"

Comment: `ng-bind-html` is what you're looking for. You'll also need to inject `$sce` into your filter and have it return `$sce.trustAsHtml(yourhtmltext);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sfFY3/)**

**html**

```
<div  ng-app='MyApp' ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="test | replace_brackets"></div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", [])
.filter('replace_brackets', function($compile){
    return function(text) {
        var output = text.replace(/\[/g,'<').replace(/\]/g,'>');

        return output;
    };
});

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "[div class='rating-container']Visible[/div]";
});
```

Comment: I use this {{post.rating.html | replace_brackets }} but you made it a little different.

Comment: Your solution work in jsfiddle. My does not. I might need to change how I work with angularjs in this case.

Comment: can you give me a JSFiddle, and tell what you want

Comment: I made a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/yN6vr/1/. For some reason it does not convert the {{ to code but hopefully you can still see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Almost, but it does not work like expected. The less-than character is visible in your last fiddle. It should be as a html character.

Comment: means you want `rating-container` only to be printed

Comment: I updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/yN6vr/5/. Less-than characters should still exist but not be converted to the text version of the less-than characters.

Comment: Awesome! Works great!

Comment: I changed to angularjs1.2 and then it does not work anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/yN6vr/9/